# Solving T(n) time complexity that contains "variables"

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

So, I need to find the T(n) and then Big-O (tight upper bound) for the following piece of code:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) {
    for(int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2) {
        for(int k = j; k < n; k += 2) {
            sum += i + j * k;
        }
    }
}
```

Now from what I calculated for the loops, **first loop runs log(n) times**, **second loop runs (log(n) * log(n)) times** and the third loop is the one which is causing confusion, because I believe **it runs for (n - j)/2 times**. My question is can I **assume it to be n/2 times**, because I think it won't be a tight upper bound if I do that. Or is there a different approach that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2) // (1)
    for(int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2) // (2)
        for(int k = j; k < n; k += 2) // (3)
```

For the first iteration of (3) (where `k = j = n`) no iteration will occur. After `j` is divided by 2 the third loop will run (n/2)/2 or n/4 times. After the third iteration of (2), (3) will run n/4/2 or n/8 times. We can sum the running time as follows:

```
n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ... + n/2^k
```

This can also be written as:

```
n * (1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ... + 1/2^k)
```

Which asymptotically is in `O(n)`.

Comment: A very good explanation, got the point perfectly, marked your answer as the solution! Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question. Let give `n` a real number and see how it's going. Say, `n=100`. If we only look at the two inner loops

```
j        k
100      None
50       50, 52, ..., 98
25       25, 27, ..., 99
12       12, 14, ..., 98
6        6, 8, ..., 98
3        3, 5, ..., 99
1        1, 3, ..., 99
```

As you can see, the complexity of the third loop is actually `O(n)`. Especially when `n` is a very large number, it will be close to `Θ(n)`